# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type when added jpeg or mp3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpack, package, babel-loader

I am working on a rails app with vue on front end. I am getting this error when try to add any image or mp3 file to my project. Please help me resolve this issue. Below is my environment.js file.

I am using webpack version

```
@rails/webpacker": "^3.2.0"
```

Below is the home.vue file which is causing the issue. When I try to add this mp3 file I get that error.
home.vue

```
<template>
  <div>         
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 sm4 md4 class="hidden-xs-only">
          <p>
            <!-- <a :href="require('images/company-overview.mp3')" target="_blank" title="Read Article">
              <img src="../../images/company-logo.png"/>
            </a> -->
          </p>
        </v-flex>   
      </v-layout>    
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
  };
</script>
```

environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const coffee =  require('./loaders/coffee');
const vue =  require('./loaders/vue')
environment.loaders.append('coffee', coffee);
environment.loaders.append('vue', vue)
environment.loaders.append('jshint', {
  test: /\.js$/, // include .js files
  enforce: "pre", // preload the jshint loader
  exclude: /node_modules/, // exclude any and all files in the node_modules folder
  use: [{
      loader: "jshint-loader"
  }]
});

environment.loaders.append('signature_pad', {
  test: /\.js?$/,
      include: [/node_modules\/signature_pad/],
  use: [{
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
      presets: [['env', { 'modules': false, 'targets': { 'node': 4 } }]]
    }
  }],
});

environment.loaders.append('sass', {
  test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
  use: [
    // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
    'style-loader',
    // Translates CSS into CommonJS
    'css-loader',
    // Compiles Sass to CSS
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        // Prefer `dart-sass`
        implementation: require('sass'),
      },
    },
  ],
});

const resolver = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.js'
    }
  }
};
environment.config.merge(resolver);

module.exports = environment;
```

Comment: Can you post any of the upload-specific code? Is it a form?

Comment: @Chiperific I have added home.vue file code which is causing the issue.

Comment: This looks like a Vue.js issue, not a Rails issue, BUT, does `href="require('images/company-overview.mp3')"` actually resolve to a Rails path in your app? If your assets are precompiled, you'll need something like `image_path`:https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/image_path

Comment: Did you find this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/211#issuecomment-301795040

Comment: @Chiperific I am not able to figureout how Can I add this in my environment.js file. Can you help me with that?

Comment: This might also help: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/211#issuecomment-282839290

Comment: I'm not a Vue.js person, but it looks like you need to set this up in "the config of the file-loader (where `png` etc are handled)" if that means anything to you.

Comment: @Chiperific Okay I ll try to find a solution